# Unclear, possibly abandoned question - should we close?

Tags: discussion

This question was posted yesterday:

[Javascript - Food totals array crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37026539/javascript-food-totals-array-crashing)

I posted an answer to it, and the code was changed(improved to remove trivial mistakes, as the OP claimed the real problem wasn't with the outlined mistakes).

Another answer has been posted, but the question seems to have gone dormant since. No updates, no follow-ups, code is still vague, and looks incomplete.

The question was confusing, so I already have raised a (pending)'unclear what you're asking' flag.

What do others think? Should the question be closed, or 1 day is still too early to be able to say anything?

Comment: abandoned is after a year ... not everyone is so fanatic that they check back daily...

Comment: It's a ***day*** old!  The dust hasn't even settled on it yet!

Answer (score 6):

Too early?  If the question is unclear then the question closure is 1 day too late!  The question should have been closed *immediately* if it wasn't clear, and you *certainly* shouldn't have posted an answer to it if it's not clear what the problem is.

> No updates, no follow-ups

None of that has any bearing at all on whether or not you should close it.  If it's unclear, vote to close it as unclear *right away*.  If the author is able to fix it, it can be reopened just as quickly.  Whether the author is actively interacting with the question has no effect on whether or not the question meets closure criteria though.  (It would affect whether you'd consider *deleting* it; as you'd only want to delete a question that the author (or someone else) isn't going to improve, but deletion and closure are very different in that regard.)

Comment: Well, I took more of a 'wait and see' approach - see if it's just me missing something or the question really is too vague. Maybe it's VLQ too I think - but that's going a bit far. When hope seemed low I flagged it as unclear.

Comment: @cst1992 And I'm specifically telling you that you shouldn't have.  If the question isn't clear, vote to close *immediately*.  Don't wait around, and *certainly* don't post answers that don't actually answer the question.  VLQ is basically a way of saying you think it should be closed but can't be bothered to choose the correct flag reason.  There's no real need to use that flag, just vote to close for the correct close reason.

Comment: Got it. Will keep in mind :)