# Is it bad manners to edit answers to questions so their references to the original code is updated?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

Occasionally, I have seen a couple of cases where:

1. User A asks a question and includes some code.
2. User B answers the question and refers to the code included in the question.
3. User A edits his question making (sometimes trivial) edits to the code in order to make it simpler, or whatever.
4. User A then edits User B's answer so that its references to the original code are updated. The suggested edit is placed on the review queue.
5. The community disagrees on whether the edit should be approved or not.

Now, the point is that a careful review of the editing would clearly reveal that no changes are made other than to reflect the updated code presented on the question itself. I even saw cases where the final verdict was to reject the edit suggestion, much to my disfavour.

This sure appears to be a tricky topic. Unfortunately I can't give any examples now other than [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12264759) added yesterday by myself, which led me to ask this here in the first place.

My first impression is that users who reject such suggested edits don't actually take the time to review them properly. However, since this appears to be somewhat usual, I have a feeling there may be something else involved, specially considering that the nature of the edit is made obvious in the edit summary, in my case at least.

My question is the one from the title: Would making such edit suggestions be considered bad manners? If so, what would be the proper steps to be taken when an user updates the code samples included in their questions? It doesn't seem feasible to add a comment for every existing answer.

Comment: Really you just shouldn't be making entirely superfluous changes to the code like this in the first place, removing the problem entirely.  The change isn't adding any value at all.

Comment: Related: [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260245/3258851)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have full editing rights (2k+ rep), this sort of thing is ok.

Until then, you should avoid these sorts of edits.

Keep in mind that the reviewers will see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, as you may know, if you are to edit a question, then you shouldn't be touching the code for edits other than just formatting or indentation(as it may "fix" the problem that the user is having, invalidating answers that address it).

In the same manner, an answer shouldn't be posted unless such trivial errors are already sorted out in the question. An answer shouldn't be used to point out those trivial errors, rather, comments should be used.

That means that point number 2 shouldn't arise at all, and consequently, neither should 4 and 5.

I found this out the hard way: 
[Unclear, possibly abandoned question - should we close?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322489/unclear-possibly-abandoned-question-should-we-close)

My answer was of low quality, and eventually got deleted. I should have made sure the question was clear before answering, or flagged the question as 'unclear what you're asking'. It's user B's responsibility that the question actually shows the user's real problem rather than such trivial errors.